# How to keep internal var in companion object

Tags: kotlin, proguard

I have the following class definition:

```
class SomeObject {

    companion object {
       internal val instance = SomeObject()
    }

}
```

This class is self sustaining, and is just listening to events.
My problem is that proguard removes the "instance" field.

What do I write in my proguard file to keep the instance field (it can be obfuscated, but i want to keep the field from being deemed as "unused code")

Comment: why don't you use an `object` instead of `class`? in the bytecode it translates to something similar as what you wrote... i.e. instead of your shown code you use`object SomeObject { }`...

Comment: @Roland maybe one needs different instances of `SomeObject` (after adding more properties to it) and therefore cannot use an `object` which is a singleton.

Comment: the var is a typo for writing in SO ;)

Comment: ok... then my comments regarding the culprit are irrelevant... now I only have the question whether this should be a singleton or not... or what is the purpose of having this internal `instance`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proguard rule should look like this:

```
-keepclassmembers class com.your.package.path.SomeObject {
    public static ** Companion;
}
```

This way you can specify classes of which the companion object should not be removed (including the property).

Comment: in theory it does, but my actual problem was not that ;)